# Using MySQL in Javascript

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord

So i'm working on a discord bot with discord.js where it counts the amount of times someone says "XD" that bit works but i'm trying to make it so to a database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUYM3.png)

Thats my code but I get the following error

[Shell Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBzV6.png)

Comment: In order to help the answering process could you provide the code snippet and the error code is the question ? You can create [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to declare a variable inside an object.

You either need to make a function, or write that code another place (like a callback), but without knowing what npm module you are using it is difficult to help you.

You need to read the documentation of the module you are using.